# How do I access Window Resources in WinUI 3

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I've just started working on a WinUi 3 (Desktop) project and have got blocked trying to add Window resources to a Window.

I would have thought the following would work. However there appears to be no Resources property.

```
<Window.Resources>
    
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it was a design choice, to quote [Miguel](https://github.com/marb2000), a member of Microsoft, from a Github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4114#issuecomment-774332811):

> [...] the Window object doesn't have Resource property like WPF, for instance. It was a design decision [...]

The alternative is to use the dictionary within the component's context, for instance:

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.Resources>
   <!-- My resources -->
  </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hm, doesn't look like I can access resources in `ListView` if those resources are defined within `ListView.Resources` :/ What a strange design decision.

Comment: I ended up moving the resource I needed to `App.xaml`.

Comment: An example as an answer would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the resource in the root control of your window.

```
<Window ...>
    <Border ...>
        <Border.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            </Style>
        </Border.Resources>
        <Button ... />
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right - there are no Window resources. You can have globally shared resources by making App resources, or you can have `<page>` and `<Control>` level resources.

What your probably want is to define your resource dictionaries in App.xml

```
<Application
x:Class="BOMCheck.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:converters="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Converters"
xmlns:helpers="using:BOMCheck.Helpers"
xmlns:local="using:BOMCheck"
xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Comment: Where are the rest from your answer?